# Make xml.etree.ElementTree work with Eclipse PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I want to work with the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module of python but I'm not able to `import` it to the script, `ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree`. I'm totally sure that module is working because I'm able to run it without eclipse!
How to make it work with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the xml's module paths in `Preferance->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter` `C:\Python27\lib\xml`

and import module in this way
`import etree.ElementTree as ET`